# How can I reduce query time to less than 1 second?

Tags: c++, sql, oracle, sqlite

The size of my SQLite database is 3GB and the number of rows in `ANC_TB` is 1 million. It takes about 5 seconds to execute the query :

```cpp
db_mgr().ExecuteQuery(ToString(_T("SELECT CORE_MAX_PIN_BURNUP FROM ANC_TB WHERE UNIT_ID='%s' AND  CYCLE_NUM=%d AND FA_ID='%s' ORDER BY CORE_MAX_PIN_BURNUP DESC LIMIT 1"),
                               pi().ucms,
                               itr->cycle,
                               itr->fa_id
                              )
                              .GetBuffer(0)
                      );
  
if (db_mgr().Start())
{
    itr->a_Max_Pin_Burnup = db_mgr().Get_int(_T("CORE_MAX_PIN_BURNUP"));
}
```

How can I reduce query time to less than 1 second? I tried increasing memory size :

```cpp
sqlite3_exec(mpDB, "PRAGMA cache_size=100000;", NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: Why did you tag "oracle"?

Comment: Did you create an index?

Comment: How much time does it take without C++ code, like using some DB tool to open SQLite database?

Comment: 5 seconds to read a million records and 3gb of data sounds pretty good to me? How fast is your disk drive? If you want better performance you'll probably need some sort of dedicated database cluster rather than sqlite

Comment: There is an "anc_tb" table in the Oracle database containing one million records without using an index. Performance may be slower compared to SQLite tables when there is less data in the table.

Comment: SQLiteCPP COde
'CppSQLite3Query* SQLiteDB::ExecuteQuery(wchar_t* strQuery)
{
 rs.finalize();
 char* query = WCToMB(strQuery);
 rs = sqlite_db.execQuery(query);
 if (rs.checkVM())
  return NULL;
 return &rs;
}'

ORACLE OCI CODE
'OCI_Statement* OracleDB::ExecuteQuery(OCI_Connection* conn, CString sql)
{
 OCI_Statement* stmt = OCI_StatementCreate(conn);
 if (OCI_Parse(stmt, (CStringA)sql))
 {
  if (OCI_Execute(stmt))
  {
   if (OCI_Commit(conn))
    return stmt;
  }
 }
 return NULL;
}'

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: just adding an index for column CORE_MAX_PIN_BURNUP should speed it up according to your ordering clause and just needing the first row.

Comment: How do I add an index? Do I need to create a new column and give an index to all the data? Since there is a lot of data that matches my conditions, I am using "Limit 1" to get the last CRE_MAX_PIN_BURNUP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your predicate is:

```
WHERE UNIT_ID='%s' AND  CYCLE_NUM=%d AND FA_ID='%s'
```

Assuming all of these are high cardinality (lots of distinct values) columns, you should have a single index on all three. Without knowing what other SQLs may hit the table or the cardinality of each column, I can't really advise on exact order, but at least get all three into an index:

```
CREATE INDEX myindex ON mytable (unit_id,fa_id,cycle_num)
```

If you are firing this SQL at  high volume (millions of executions), then you can also benefit from adding core_max_pin_burnup to the *end* of the index column list in order to avoid hitting the table altogether:

```
CREATE INDEX myindex ON mytable (unit_id,fa_id,cycle_num,core_max_pin_burnup)
```

It *must* go at the end, after any columns you are using for your access predicates. However, this is unnecessary and just wasted space if your execution volume is relatively low. The main thing is indexing high cardinality columns that your SQL has access predicates on.

Lastly, I would advise rewriting the SQL to use bind variables, not stringing together a string with the lookup values embedded in the string. You will cause shared pool issues by creating unsharable cursors, and that also adds to your execution time.

Comment: You can also add `CORE_MAX_PIN_BURNUP` for the sorting.

Comment: That would likely require using the INDEX_DESC hint to get Oracle to use scan the index in descending order. Without the hint, in my experience, the optimizer doesn't seem like choose descending scans even if it would permit a sort-less order by. If the query cardinality is low, which I suspect it is, the order by will hardly be felt anyway.

Comment: Interesting. I would have thought that Oracle would be able to read the index in reverse order (since it's double linked). PostgreSQL certainly does.

Comment: It can, it just usually doesn't choose to do so. You typically have to nudge it with a hint.

Comment: Your data contains duplicates for UNIT_ID, CYCLE_NUM, and FA_ID, but CORE_MAX_PIN_BURNUP values are different for each one. Among them, you only want the data with the highest BURNUP value.